# How to improve this query performance by indexing properly?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, index-tuning

I have following select query, and I need to improve the performance of this query. Can anyone suggest me how to convert the clustered index scan to index seek?

```
DECLARE @now DateTime;        
DECLARE @currentweekstart DateTime;        
DECLARE @currentweekend DateTime;     
SET @now = getDate();        
SET @currentweekstart = DATEADD(        
                 DD,        
                 -(DATEPART(DW, @now - 7) - 1),        
                 @now - 7);         
SET @currentweekend = DATEADD(        
               DD,        
               7 - (DATEPART(DW, @now - 7)),        
               @now - 7);     

  SELECT  CHINFO.CHILDID,COUNT(*) AS CURRENTWEEKPOTTYBREAKS        
          FROM  BKA.CHILDINFORMATION CHINFO         
  JOIN  BKA.CHILDEVENTS CHE         
         ON CHE.CHILDID = CHINFO.CHILDID          
  WHERE TYPE ='POTTYBREAK'        
          AND CHE.ADDDATE BETWEEN @currentweekstart AND @currentweekend         
           GROUP BY CHINFO.CHILDID
```

[image]

**Primary Keys:**

> TableName --> ColumnName
>
> CHILDINFORMATION-->ChildId
>
> CHILDEVENTS-->EventId

**Foreign Keys:**

> CHILDEVENTS-->Here ChildId is the foreign key reference of
>   CHILDINFORMATION table

**NonClustered Indexes:**

> CHILDINFORMATION-->No nonclustered indexes
>
> ChildEvents-->IX_ChildEvents_Type-->Type include EventId
>
> ChildEvents-->IX_ChildEvents_Type_AddDate-->Type,AddDate
>
> ChildEvents-->IX_ChildEvents_Adddate_Type-->Adddate,Type include
>   ChildId,EventId

Comment: What happens when you remove the BETWEEN and use `CHE.ADDDATE >= @currentweekstart AND CHE.ADDDATE < @currentweekstart`  ?

Comment: What have you learned from your first ['improve performance'](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65444/how-to-improve-this-queries-performance-by-indexing-properly) question on converting scans to seeks? It's all well and good asking, but we can't do your job for you if you're not learning.

Comment: I was reading yesterday about indexes and find this in slideshare: http://www.slideshare.net/myxplain/how-to-design-indexes-really-27839849 hope it helps

Comment: @MarkSinkinson am not asking you to do my job.i am trying to learn it.If you are interested to help me please help

Comment: @MikaelEriksson CHILDID is a clustered index in BKA.CHILDINFORMATION table

Comment: @JamesAnderson if i remove that between part it is throwing an missing index for CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ChildEvents_Type_ChildId 
    ON BKA.ChildEvents (Type) include (ChildID)

Comment: @bala3569 As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with having a Clustered Index Scan in this situation. If you're not filtering records from this table (which it looks like you are), then a scan will be the most appropriate method of retrieving the data.

Alternatively, flip the query to `SELECT FROM BKA.CHILDEVENTS` and `JOIN BKA.CHILDINFORMATION` to see if that will have any effect.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson i have tried flipping the query but still no luck

Comment: Then I don't believe that there's an issue with you having a scan on that table. You're not filtering, so there is no part of the index to 'seek'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a foreign key from `CHILDEVENTS` to `CHILDINFORMATION` and you don't select any column from the child information table, you can skip that table. One less join will certainly not hurt:

```
SELECT CHE.CHILDID, COUNT(*) AS CURRENTWEEKPOTTYBREAKS        
FROM  BKA.CHILDEVENTS AS CHE           
WHERE CHE.TYPE ='POTTYBREAK'        
  AND CHE.ADDDATE BETWEEN @currentweekstart AND @currentweekend         
GROUP BY CHE.CHILDID ;
```

As for indexing, the existing index on `(Adddate,Type) INCLUDE (ChildId, EventId)` does not look very good for this query. I would try replacing it (in fact removing both those `AddDate-Type` indexes) with an index on:

```
(Type, AddDate) INCLUDE (ChildId)
```

Comment: This will then remove that Clustered Index Scan as the table is no longer being hit.

Answer (score 0):

Best you can achieve with this exact query and CHILDINFORMATION is a (nonclustered) index scan, if you add a nonclustered index on ChildId in the CHILDINFORMATION table. It's more efficient than a clustered index scan. See [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3041/when-sql-server-nonclustered-indexes-are-faster-than-clustered-indexes/) and [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/the-smiling-dba/2012/04/02/execution-plans-table-clustered-index-and-non-clustered-index-scan/) .
It's going to be a scan, since you're not filtering, as Mark Sinkinson mentioned.

But, as ypercube said in his answer, you can even skip the join.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that the event type is in the child events table, hence the join is needed. I noticed that a large part of the cost is doing a sort. You can avoid sorts by having the right columns in an index in the right order. Here are two indexes that you should probably have. Fair warning, I am an Oracle DBA, not a SQL Server DBA. So the syntax might not be correct. Also notice that all of the columns that you need are in the indexes, hence SQL Server won't have to read both the index and the table. this is how I would do it in an Oracle database, it should work for SQL Server as well. But test and you will know.

Counting potty breaks, sounds like a George Orwell book? ;-)

```
CREATE INDEX CHILDEVENTS_IDX1      ON CHILDEVENTS ( TYPE, CHILDID )
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CHILDINFORMATION_IDX1 ON CHILDID     ( ADDDATE, CHILDID )
```

Comment: `AddDate` is in the `ChildEvents` table, not the ChildInformation one.

Comment: For `ChildEvents` table it is enough if `ChildID` is the `INCLUDE`, doesn't need to be a key column (no filtering on it).

Comment: Right, then you want to make sure that you have this index: CREATE INDEX CHILDEVENTS_IDX1 ON CHILDEVENTS ( TYPE, AddDate, CHILDID )